# Notify of a model property changed on a view in the DevExpress datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, devexpress

I'm working on a WPF application using DevExpress, and also using the mvvm pattern, and have the following problem:

- I have a view model that has a boolean property (for instance IsChecked)
- I have a view that is a devexpress data grid that is bound to a collection of the above mentioned view model items
- A row of that devexpress data grid is of type check box, and it's bound to the IsChecked property
- I have a data template for the row of devexpress grid for showing a line in the row, if IsChecked is true

All this works fine when I check/uncheck the check box column in the data grid.... The problem is when I change the model property's value: the view does not change....

The model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

It seems to be that DevExpress makes a wrapper for each item, and then does not notify the view when the model's property has changed.

Comment: Post the code in the Model for how you are changing the property's value. As well as the code for the property itself.

Comment: Could it be that you forgot to specify Mode=TwoWay on the binding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After search into the DevExpress's [Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/), I could not find anything that helps me to solve this issues. But thanks to this nice [application (Snoop)](http://code-inside.de/blog-in/2013/01/21/snoop-firebug-for-wpf-applications/) I get solve it.

The thing is that the DevExpress's grid collection do not behave like the other WPF's standard collections. In any WPF's collection each row (or item in a collection) has in the `DataContext` the ViewModel (or any class of the collection type). The DevExpress's grid do not works like that...

Each `GridRow` item of the DevExpress's grid has an object of type `RowData` in the `DataContext`, and each cell (are of type `GridCellContentPresenter`) has an object of type `EditGridCellData`. As we can see this objects are not the same type of our collection.

So how we can do any two-way binding between our view model, and our view row or cell item in the grid?

### If we are making a row template:

The object that is in the `DataContext` in each row is of type `RowData`. This type have a property named `DataContext`, this property is of type `RowTypeDescriptor` (like a wrapper of our collection type). This do not works for making our binding. **BUT** the type `RowData` has a property namde `Row` in which  we can find our collection's type row object, so the only thing that we have to do is to make a binding to this property. For instance, in this case we want that a line cross my row if a bool field is set to true:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myRowTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <dx:MeasurePixelSnapper>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="defaultRowPresenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding View.DefaultDataRowTemplate}" />
            </dx:MeasurePixelSnapper>               
            <Path Data="M5.496,10.5 L508,10.5" Fill="#FFF" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF040404" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Margin="0" Visibility="{Binding Row.AnyModelBoolProperty, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

### If we are making a cell template:

In this case is a bit more complex. because the object `EditGridCellData` has not any property where we can find our collection's object type. The only we can find here is a property called `Data` in which we can find a object of type `RowTypeDescriptor`, so do not work fine. We need to solve this using a ancestor type binding. See this example:

```
    <dxg:GridColumn x:Name="dateRow" FieldName="Date" Header="Date">
                    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <dxe:DateEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" DateTime="{Binding DataContext.Row.Date, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dx:StackVisibleIndexPanel}}}" IsEnabled="{Binding DataContext.Row.DateEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dx:StackVisibleIndexPanel}}}" MinValue="{Binding DataContext.Row.DateMinValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dx:StackVisibleIndexPanel}}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
    </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Here we have a date control that will be bound to the model and will be correctly notified. Hope this could be useful for every one that had this problem. It is a real head ache.